# Saving Array in Core Data with Custom Class

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

Below i want to achieve. I want to save an Array(Which is array of dictionaries) and at the time of retrieving i want to retrieve as it is, Array of Dictionaries. So what i tried so far, i have created an entity which have a attribute say empName: Transformable, While on the right side i have create the custom class as NSArray. Please refer below image. [image]
`

```
let employee: NSArray = [["Name": "Apple"]]
let empDetails = EmpDetail(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: context)
empDetails.empName = employee
```

Its get saved without any error in context.

Below when i want to retrieve this As NSArray it just show me something below output.

```
(entity: CarDetails; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://32E7B589-89B0-41C7-BFCC-0E4E91AE2358/CarDetails/p1> ; data: {\n    empName = \"(\\n        {\\n        Name = Apple;\\n    }\\n)\";\n    empCode = nil;\n})"
```

Want to know do i really need to change it in NSKeyArchieve to save it as binary data while my custom class says its an Array. 
What am i missing here to retrieve it as NSArray and use it as to a normal Array to fetch its Key and Dictionaries. 
Any help or suggestion would be appreciate. 
thank you.

Comment: you have array of dictionary ,right? If yes, keep it as NSData type & save as  archived object in db

Comment: We use archived object when we have Binary data as Data Type. While i do have transformable.

Comment: have you tried to save as empDetails.setValue(employee as, forKey: "empName") ??

Comment: Your output looks like you have printed the CoreData entity (which is a subclass of NSManagedObject), rather than the `empName` attribute of that object.  The data: section of your output shows the attribute values and seems to have the array.  But you should consider whether you really want to store that array in one attribute of one entity - or whether each element of the array should be a separate instance of the entity (with attributes corresponding to your dictionary keys).

Comment: I want to save an array which contains a dictionary. As both data are associated so i choose the transformable property.